# Nutch index writer

Tags: nutch, azure-cognitive-search

Has anyone created a custom Apache Nutch index writer for Azure Search? I want to use the Apache Nutch crawler to crawl some websites and then push the crawled content in an Azure Search instance. Nutch comes with a few index writers for other open source search engines and some file writers but not surprisingly, nothing specific for Azure Search.

I've scoured the web and searched these forums but haven't found an index writer for Azure Search.

I could write one of my own but I'm trying to avoid dusting off my Java skills (no offense to Java but it's not high ROI for this one little experiment).

Comment: The [indexer-cloudsearch](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-cloudsearch/) plugin (for AWS cloudsearch) might be a good starting point to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [list of available IndexWriters for Nutch](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/IndexWriters), we see things like indexer-dummy or indexer-csv. I would imagine that adapting one of those to submit content to the Azure Search API would not be much work. I would investigate what that dummy indexer does and see if that can be used.

Otherwise, the CSV writer will definitively do the job. I can think of two approaches.

1. Submit the CSV files to blob storage and configure an Azure Search Datasource and Indexer with options to pull CSV files (supported out of the box).
2. Drop the CSV files to local storage. Write some C# code to read the files and submit to Azure Search via the push API.